# Best practice in Redis is to rename the command 'FLUSHDB'. But now I get an error with Laravel when I want to clear the cache

Tags: cache, redis, laravel

In Laravel, you can set the cache to Redis. However, when I clear the cache with `php artisan cache:clear`, I get the error: `ERR unknown command 'FLUSHDB'`

I know what the problem is because I have disabled the command as one should do for best practice.

But I'm not sure what to do. Should I activate the command so I can use redis as cache?

Comment: You disabled the command before, but now you want to use it. So you enable it again. That's too simple.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok  I wasn't sure if it's a big no no

Comment: The best practice is to _rename_ the command, not necessarily _disable_ it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well sorry, I was wrong to say that I *disabled* it. With `rename-command FLUSHDB ""` I just renamed it to an empty string. However, since I'm using a framework, I'm not able to change the name of the function. (https://github.com/illuminate/cache/blob/master/RedisStore.php#L217). So I need to bring this function back. Thank you for your help